# Space complexity analysis of recursive functions

Tags: algorithm, recursion, space-complexity

During a typical interview, when asked 'what is the space complexity' of an algorithm, and if the algorithm is recursive, does the interview usually mean 'the maximum number of calls on the framestack throughout the life of the algorithm', or does he mean 'the largest number of elements in any given variables created in the function' ?

In a non-recusive algorithm, the latter definition is usually the definition of space complexity. But in recursive, we have to define both separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more information 'what is the space complexity' would refer to the total space used by the program. That is stack and heap space.

Comment: Yes, and with a recursive function, the heap size is not necessarily going to be the maximum size of structures created by the function. It could be the total size of all of them, if none of them are garbage collectable until the recursion is finished, for example.